Getting an error when Parent struct pass reference to a child struct
I am trying to have common struct between parent struct which holds a vector of children structs. CommonParams struct holds parameters the children inherit from the Parent which might be updated and so all children should have access to the up-to-date parameters.
All parent must have 1 child when created.
struct Parent<'a> {
    children: Vec<Child<'a>>,
    common_params: CommonParams,
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Parent<'a> {
    fn new(name: &str, child_name: &str, child_age: u8, address: String) -> Parent<'a> {
        let common = CommonParams {
            address,
        };
        let mut parent = Parent {
            children: Vec::new(),
            common_params: common,
            name,
        };
        let child = Child::new(&parent.common_params, child_name);
        parent.add_child(child);
        parent
    }

    fn add_child(&mut self, child: Child<'a>) {
        self.children.push(child);
    }
}

struct Child<'a> {
    common_params: &'a CommonParams,
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Child<'a> {
    fn new(common_params: &'a CommonParams, name: &'a str) -> Child<'a> {
        Child {
            common_params,
            name,
        }
    }
}

struct CommonParams {
    address: String,
}

The compiler returns an error:

9  | impl<'a> Parent<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
14 |         let mut parent = Parent {
   |             ---------- binding `parent` declared here
...
19 |         let child = Child::new(&parent.common_params, child_name);
   |                                --------------------- borrow of `parent.common_params` occurs here
20 |         parent.add_child(child);
21 |         parent
   |         ^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         move out of `parent` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `parent.common_params` is borrowed for `'a`

How can I implement this?
Thanks

The main issue is that your call Child::new() borrows &parent.common_params. However, when Parent::new() returns it moves parent. So the reference to common_params would then be invalid. What the solution is, highly depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish. One solution would be to access Child through a method on Parent, where Parent then forwards a reference to CommonParams. The super easy solution, would be to simply clone CommonParams and store CommonParams instead of &'a CommonParams in Child (same for name, i.e. String)

You're trying to create a self-referential struct. The easiest solution will be to store CommonParams in Rc.
